# How to separate specific data

Tags: c, strtok, strcpy

I am trying to extract the city from the following string;

Kmart, 200 Irwin Ne, Fort Walton Beach FL

The code I made goes through the string and I can extract this;

Fort Walton Beach FL

However, I do not understand how to effectively extract the city. I can extract the state using strlen but that is not working for the city.

```
void getCity(char strCity[], const char strLine[])
{
   char newLine[MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE+1];
   char newCity[MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE+1];

   strcpy(newLine, strLine);
   char* token = strtok(newLine, ",");

   if(token != NULL)
   {
     token = strtok(NULL,",");
     token = strtok(NULL, ",");
   } 
   strcpy(newCity, token);
   strcpy(strCity, token);
```

Comment: If the state code is always two letters, you can simply check for a space before those two letters, zap the space into a null, and what's left is the city name.  Beware short strings (erroneous data).  Your final `strcpy()` statements copy the same information to two local variables — that probably isn't what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Take the string you have (`"Fort Walton Beach FL"`) and use a reverse search for the "first" (which is really the last) space. Use e.g. [`strrchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strrchr) to do it.

Then change that space to the string terminator `'\0'` and the string will become `"Fort Walton Beach"`.

Increase the pointer to the (former) space and you have a pointer to the first character of the state, if you need that as well.

Comment: Thanks. But really quick, how would change the space to the string terminator? I'm a bit confused on that

Comment: Literally assign it `char *c = strrchr(test, ' '); if(c) *c = '\0'; else . . .`.